# oTableTools extra from datatables is not working fine

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datatables

I use this gem https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails  to add datatables to my rails app project.

I have added to application.js:

```
//=require dataTables/extras/TableTools
```

and application.css.scss:

```
*= require dataTables/extras/TableTools
*= require dataTables/extras/TableTools_JUI
```

I use this gem with twitter bootstrap and all is working fine except [OTableTools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) extra.

This is my datatable code:

```
$("#admin").dataTable({
  "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
  "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
  "bProcessing"     : true,
  "sScrollX": "100%",
  "bScrollCollapse": true,
  "bAutoWidth": false,
  "aoColumns"       : [{"sType" : "html"}, null, null, null],
  "aaSorting"       : [[0, 'asc'], [1, 'asc']],
  "bServerSide"     : true,
  "sAjaxSource"     : "/admin/admins.json",
  "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                "copy",
                "print",
                {
                    "sExtends":    "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Save",
                    "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                }
            ]
        }
}).fnSetFilteringDelay();
```

I have added `oTableTools` like inside this example http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/bootstrap.html to works with twitter bootstrap.

I can not see the buttons to export to csv, xls, and pdf format...etc

**What am I doing wrong? Where is the problem?**

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a slightly different director structure than the default TableTools example you'll need to set the sSwf path for the swf file that does the saving, i.e.:

```
"oTableTools": {
    "sSwfPath": "dataTables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
    "aButtons": ["copy", "print", {
         "sExtends": "collection",
         "sButtonText": "Save <span class=\"caret\" />",
         "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
    }]
}
```

But my understanding is that shouldn't effect the display only the functionality (actual saving and copying).

I am having the exact same problem as you. All my code is processed - I checked with [DataTables debugger](http://datatables.net/blog/DataTables_debugger) and it recognizes TableTools is being used in the DataTable.

Let me know if you figure this out!